# C#: Share properties, events, and methods across unrelated classes

Tags: c#, oop, events

I need to add the following to several unrelated classes:

```
private MyClass myclass;

private EventHandler clicked;
public event EventHandler Clicked { ... }

private bool enabled;
public bool Enabled { ... }

private void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

The problem is these classes are third-party and do not necessarily share the same immediate base class though they all eventually inherit from a class called `View`. Right now, I end up creating my own subclasses for each and copy-pasting the same code which leads to unnecessary duplication.

Any way to meaningfully refactor this?

Comment: add more code... ppl will not be able to help you with that

Comment: I'm not sure why more code is necessary. This is a design question, and it should have a generic solution IMO. Also, the code doesn't do anything special other than basic event/property handling.

Comment: if it was generic then it wouldn't be specific to you. Yeah it can be refactored... but again its your code and without context a lot of assumptions are made... and don't know if you have heard what assumptions are ;-). If its generic... then just use abstract class/inheritance/interfaces... showing that code... doesn't give me enough context to come up with anything other than use general oop techniques.

Answer (score 1):

**One of the way** is to use composition. Create class which will store all new events\properties\methods:

```
public class Properties
{
  private MyClass myclass;

  private EventHandler clicked;
  public event EventHandler Clicked { ... }

  private bool enabled;
  public bool Enabled { ... }

  private void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
}
```

Then use `Extension methods` to expand required interface (i.e. classA)

```
public static class NewInterfaces
{
   public static Properties Props(this classA)
   {  /* lookup required properties, from some associative storage */ }
}
```

Usage will look like:

```
var inst = new classA();
inst.Prop.Enabled = !inst.Prop.Enabled;
```

**Second way** it still composition, but you will use wrapper for those:

```
public class Wrapper
{
  private object _wrapped;

  public Wrapper(classA obj)
  {
    _wrapped = obj;
  }

  public Wrapper(classB obj)
  {
    _wrapped = obj;
  }

  public int WrappedProperty
  { 
    get
    {
      var instA = _wrapped as classA;
      if (instA != null)
        return instA.SomeProperty1;
      var instB = _wrapped as classB;
      if (instB != null)
        return instB.SomeProperty2;
    }
  }

  private MyClass myclass;

  private EventHandler clicked;
  public event EventHandler Clicked { ... }

  private bool enabled;
  public bool Enabled { ... }

  private void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
}
```

Second way allow you to create new hierarchy of wrapper which will contain elements without common base class.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance becomes problematic in time. I recommend using interfaces instead, you will have much more flexibility.

```
public interface INewInterfaces
{
    event EventHandler Clicked;
    bool Enabled { get; }
    void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e);
}

public class NewClassA : ClassA, INewInterfaces
{
    //...
}

public class NewClassB : ClassB, INewInterfaces
{
    //...
}
```

**Edit 1:**

If you are saying that ClassX's are very similar and you want to use the same HandleClicked implementation in all of these unrelated classes, you may use two other approaches.

1- Still inheritance

Create an interface and add all the common functions across the classes you want to use. This will put the ClassX's in the same family. And then create a class for general use.

```
public interface IExistingInterfaces
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class NewClassA : ClassA, IExistingInterfaces
{
    //Do nothing
}

public class NewClassB : ClassB, IExistingInterfaces
{
    //Do nothing
}


public class MyClassForGeneralUse : IExistingInterfaces
{
    private IExistingInterfaces _baseObject;
    public MyClassForGeneralUse(IExistingInterfaces baseObject)
    {
        _baseObject = baseObject;
    }

    //Write proxy calls for IExistingInterfaces 
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _baseObject.SomeMethod();
    }

    //Add new methods here
    public void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //...
    //...
}
```

Not: The first part is Bridge Pattern and the second part is Decorator Pattern

2- Reflection

```
  var propertyInfo = someObject.GetType().GetProperty("property name");
    if (propertyInfo == null)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Property does not exist:{0}", condition.Property));

    var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(someObject, null);
    long longValue = (long)propertyValue;

    //You can get methods in a smilar manner and execute with
    result = methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray);
```

But reflection may be overkill.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this, but ideally I'd like to refactor out not just the declaration but also the implementation.

Comment: Please see Edit 1. Is this what you meant?